# Changing all cells in a column with dropdown lists

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to replace all cells in a column with a dropdown list for using an excel macro. I'm also trying to use dynamic range as I don't know how long the list is at all times. This is my code as of right now:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("*Name of main sheet*")
Set StartCell = Range("A1")

'Find Last Row and Column
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Select Range

Worksheets("*Name of main sheet*").Activate

'replace "J2" with the cell you want to insert the drop down list
With Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
    .Delete
    'replace "=A1:A6" with the range the data is in.
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet1!A1:A6"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

I'm creating the lists with all the options for the drop down in a separate tab called `Sheet1`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `With Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Validation`?

Comment: yes @sktneer  with or without I still get runtime error 1004 method range of object _global failed

Comment: I don't see an actual "question".  Are you asking about the error?  Where are you getting the error?

Comment: Well actually I've solved the error, I'm just not quite sure how to achieve what i want to do, which is replace all the cells in a column with a drop down, I'll attach a GIF with what currently happens
https://imgur.com/a/LoxRE
I would like every option in the column with the options to appear in each drop down for each cell in the column, right now it's acting really weird

Comment: I tried your code.  It doesn't make much sense: it selects cell A1 to the last populated cell in column A, deletes the contents of those cells, and then tried to do an `Add` on a range (which isn't a valid method for a range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `.Validation` at the end of `With Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))` and use `$` to keep rows reference fixed

so the whole `With-End` block With becomes:

```
With Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Validation
    .Delete
    'replace "=A1:A6" with the range the data is in.
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet1!A$1:A$6"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

---

if you need to keep dropdowns list dynamic with Sheet1 column A not blank values then you could go as follows:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long

Dim sourceSht As Worksheet
Set sourceSht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With Worksheets("Name of main sheet")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    With .Range("A1", .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & sourceSht.name & "!" & sourceSht.Range("A1", sourceSht.Cells(sourceSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Address(True, False)
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End With
```